# Which programming languages will have problems pulling dash named column names?

Tags: php, java, python

I sometimes work in clojure, a language promoting the use of dashes in variable names (much more readable than Java camelCasing I can say). Taking this a step further, I'd favor having column name parity in one database implementation, so that column names in my code are the same as in the database. My database of choice supports this. I wonder how this would affect developers using other languages, who may have to access the same tables:

Will developers in other common languages have to go through special effort to accommodate reading dash inclusive column names? e.g. I once heard rants from PHP developers around hyphens in names of resources. Which programming languages will require extra handling for dash inclusive column names? what extent of effort will those languages require for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in clojure, but it looks very similar to LISP. Not sure what languages that will get in to trouble, but every major DBMS will. I tested with Mariadb:

```
[test]> create table tx (a-b int);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
syntax to use near '-b int)' at line 1
```

and with DB2:

```
~]$ db2 "create table tx (a-b int)"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was 
not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it 
returned: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "-b int)" was found following 
"create table tx (a".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>". 
SQLSTATE=42601
```

I suspect that all other DBMS:s will have problem as well. You can quote your way around that:

```
]$ db2 "create table tx (\"a-b\" int)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

but I would strongly advise against that.

I would create a mapper in Clojure that translates "-" to "_" and vice versa for all DBMS objects.